# Why are these answers dated before the question was asked?

Tags: bug, api, date

Does anyone know why some answers are shown with a date before the question was asked?

Here are a couple of examples:

- [Why doesn't Java have compound assignment versions of the conditional-and and conditional-or operators? (&&=, ||=)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324549/why-doesnt-java-have-compound-assignment-versions-of-the-conditional-and-and-co)
- [How to crop an image into polygon shape in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280561/how-to-crop-an-image-into-polygon-shape-in-ios)

In the first post, some answers are from October 2009, but the question is dated on Feb 2010. In the second post, the first answer is from August 29, 2012, but the question is dated on September 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's consistent with the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2324549/timeline) - the 'asked' event is usually at the very bottom, but here it's in the middle:

[image]

What happened here is that the question was [merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/merged-questions/info) - the answers were originally posted to a question from 2009, but were later moved to a newer question which was probably better worded than the original question.

[image]